# Cannot connect CSS file to HTML file

Tags: html, css

Some days ago I started learning HTML. Now I am trying to embed a CSS file which should change the font of the body, but it doesn't ;).

I have one very simple HTML file:

```
<head>                                             
    <meta charset="UTF-8">                         
    <title>TEXT</title>                            
    <meta name="description" content="Darum gehts auf der Page">  
    <meta name="keywords" content="fugenspachtel, silikon" >    
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">        
    <style>
        article {
            color: green;                          
        }
        h1 {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">    

</head>

<body>                                             
    <header>                                       
        <h1 style="color: red">TEXT <br> <span>TEXT</span></h1>      
    </header>

    <section>                                      
        <article>
        <p>TEXT</p>
        <img src="images/spachtel1.jpg"><br>
        <img src="images/spachtel1.jpg"><br><br>
        </article>
    </section>

    <footer>                                          
        <h3>text<br>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS file with the color for the body:

```
@font-face {                                                    
    font-family: 'alex_brushregular';
    src: url('alexbrush-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('alexbrush-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('alexbrush-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('alexbrush-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('alexbrush-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('alexbrush-regular-webfont.svg#alex_brushregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {                                                          
    font-family: 'alex_brushregular', 'sans-serif';
}
```

I have one project folder and inside that folder I have one more folder named CSS. Inside that folder there are all the fonts in different format (e.g. .ttf, .eot and so on).

Here is the folder structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV71N.png

Comment: Is the css and font files in the same folder?

Comment: Check your file paths...

Comment: yes they are ;) the structure is this: http://i.imgur.com/tM5Cvko.png

Comment: And I do not see a body color anywhere, what are you talking about?

Comment: link is a self-closing tag, ie. <link href="" type="" />

Comment: @circusdei — The question is about HTML, not XHTML. If that was the problem then the OP would be suffering from the Yellow Screen Of Death.

Comment: Can you look at console of your browser. Is there any error? (F12)

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Check to see if you are requesting the URLs you expect and getting the responses you expect.

Comment: You're not accessing the page over HTTPS by any chance, are you?

Comment: To make the console easier, use the Fonts filter, you may find the CSS file requests fonts for a relative path and not where you think you are requesting them. This isn't the font path your were looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss the letter `s` at the end of stylesheet, use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheets.css">
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
```

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem

Comment: @Richi888 You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to load `stylesheet.css` while the css file in your folder is called `stylesheets.css`. So simply renaming this should fix the problem

Comment: you made my day. thanks man

Answer (score -2):

Your link must look like

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file">
```

In general you missed the type.

Comment: The type attribute is optional.

Comment: This is not the answer

Comment: While the type attribute is optional, I think it's generally a good idea to just include it. May it be for just that little extra readability.